# Como resolver ModuleBuildError

Tags: quasar

Aconteceu que depois de atualizar o ubunto-18.04 para 20.04 e atualizar o nodejs, começou a dar erro no Module build.

> Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cj  s.js):
> Error: Missing binding /home/user/frontloja/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-64/binding.node
> Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment  : Linux 64-bit   with Node.js 10.x
> Found bindings for the following environments:
> - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 12.x

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUÇÃO - No meu caso resolvi assim:**

1. Removi /node_modules da minha aplicação.
2. Depois reinstalei com `yarn install`.